# jQuery ajax, beforeSend and slide to load target

Tags: jquery, ajax, slide

I'm using this code to load data with ajax.
Before sending the request I use `beforeSend` to slide up the content. Then on ajax success I want to slide down the response:

```
function  ajax_upd(actionTypeUrl,target){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:'rtr.php?data='+actionTypeUrl,
    cache: false,
    dataType:"json",
        beforeSend: function(){
            if(typeof target !== 'undefined'){
                $('#'+target).slideUp('fast');
            }
        },
        success: function(res) {
            if(typeof target !== 'undefined'){
                updateTarget(res,target);
            }
    }
  });
}

function updateTarget(res,target){
    var content = res.content||res;
        $('#'+target).slideDown().html(content);
        var redBar = res.redBar||false;
        if(redBar){
            $('#main-bar-content').html(redBar);
        }
}
```

My problem is that I would like to add a slideDown action on slideUp complete, and then trigger the ajax success function only once the slide down animation is complete.

Can I do that?

Comment: Make the ajax call, on success trigger the slide, include a callback function in the slide call (executes after slide has finished) which makes use of the data that the ajax retreived.

Comment: But in this way the slideUp animation wouldn't be triggered only after the ajax call is finished? I need it to run to show a loader while the ajax call is executed..

Comment: Slide up in beforeSend, down in success